# Access Object Properties in JavaScript JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am working on some basic object projects to get into using them and tying in JSON as well.  However, I am missing something as I keep being returned 'undefined' when trying to access nested properties.

The goal is to create a new scene object and load the content based on the scene name I am passing.

```
function newScene(name) {
    var sceneName = name;

    this.sceneDetails = function() {

        var theDetails = {
            "home": [
                { "title": "Home Page",
                "desc": "This home page is the homiest of all home pages." }
            ],
            "about": [
                { "title": "The About Page",
                "desc": "This page is about stuff." }
            ]
        }
        console.log(theDetails[sceneName]['title']);
    }
}


var thePage = new newScene('home');
var thePageBuild = thePage.sceneDetails();
```

When running this I am given 'undefined' as opposed to the actual Home title.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank!

Comment: Check your structure again, you have an array, you have to access it by index, then access the object.

Comment: change your log line to `console.log(theDetails[sceneName][0]['title']);`

Comment: As @elclanrs pointed out, your scene objects are inside arrays. I assume you would just want to remove the `[]` around the scene objects. Then it will behave as you expect.

Comment: In this case you could access via theDetails[sceneName][0].title. Better would be to eliminate the array altogether and then you could use your original call.

Comment: moreover your structure isnt make much sense. the var 'theDetails shouldn't be inside your function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the title and description to an array, so the actual details are located at

```
console.log(theDetails[sceneName][0]['title']);
```

I'm suspecting this wasn't what you wanted, so change the theDetails assignment to this and the code should work just fine:

```
var theDetails = {
    "home": { 
        "title": "Home Page",
        "desc": "This home page is the homiest of all home pages."
    },
    "about": { 
        "title": "The About Page",
        "desc": "This page is about stuff." 
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function newScene(name) {
    var sceneName = name;

    this.sceneDetails = function() {

        var theDetails = {
            "home": [
                { "title": "Home Page",
                "desc": "This home page is the homiest of all home pages." }
            ],
            "about": [
                { "title": "The About Page",
                "desc": "This page is about stuff." }
            ]
        }
        console.log(theDetails[sceneName][0].title);
    }
}


var thePage = new newScene('home');
var thePageBuild = thePage.sceneDetails();
```

This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nLJf/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have home and about set to arrays, you need to access them like this:

```
console.log(theDetails[sceneName][0]['title']);
```

or restructure the json like this:

```
   var theDetails = {
        "home": 
            { "title": "Home Page",
            "desc": "This home page is the homiest of all home pages." },
        "about": 
            { "title": "The About Page",
            "desc": "This page is about stuff." }

    }
```

Comment: John Sterling was first, with the exact same answer

Comment: Funny, because the guy copied one of my answer as well :)